# Is it possible to find .m files of Foundation framework?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Would be nice to take a look on .m files of Foundation framework. Can I find them somewhere?
I found couple of similar topics here, looks like only Apple have those files, but maybe somebody know. Or maybe there is another way to understand mechanics behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that Apple released as open source can be found [here](http://opensource.apple.com/). Specifically what's available of Core Foundation is [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.11/).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [opensource.apple.com](http://opensource.apple.com),or you can directly to [CoreFunction](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF)

Answer (score 0):

No. It's closed source.

You can look at OpenStep source and it may give you an idea of how things might be implemented.

As others note you can look at a lot but not all CF source many implementation details will be similar at least conceptually but not always.

The point though is that you really shouldn't need to see the source implementation to use the libraries.